# Should I use different sized icons for iOS and Android in a forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a forms application with a tab bar.  For the iOS I created these icons:

```
ionicons_2-0-1_ios-pause-outline_25.png
ionicons_2-0-1_ios-pause-outline_25@2x.png
ionicons_2-0-1_ios-pause-outline_2523x.png
```

They are sized 25*25, 50*50 and 75*75

From what I have read I believe these to be the correct sizes.

However can someone give me advice on the sizes and naming conventions for the Android side of the application.

I was told that the filenames might need to be different.  Also how can it work if I want to use one icon for iOS and another for Android. Currently I specify icons like this:

```
var homePage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
{
   Title = "Home",
   Icon = "ionicons_2-0-1_ios-home-outline_25.png"
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you probably want to seperate those.

You can read everything on working with different images on the [documentation page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/). Each platform has very specific guidelines on the right image sizes, also depending on the controls you use them on. Just Google for 'icon sizes' or 'human interface guidelines' in conjunction with Android or iOS. Also, you might want to look into the [MFractor](https://www.mfractor.com/) plugin, which has a (paid) function to generate the right sizes for you which really saves you time.

For **Android** you might want to **avoid using hyphens**, since they are known to cause trouble.

To distinquish platforms, you can use constructions like this, for XAML:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="Android, UWP">0</On>
            <On Platform="iOS">0,20,0,0</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
</ContentPage>
```

And in code:

```
switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.iOS:
        this.Padding = new Thickness(0,20,0,0);
        break;
    case Device.Android:
    case Device.UWP:   
    case Device.macOS:
    default:
        // This is just an example. You wouldn't actually need to do this, since Padding is already 0 by default.
        this.Padding = new Thickness(0);
        break;
}
```

(Code samples from [xamarinhelp.com](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-onplatform-runtimeplatform/))

While this shows it for `Padding` you can apply it on strings and apply it to your situation. However, you do not *have* to use different filenames. You can name them identically but just use different icons. Also the platform will figure out which resolution to get or postfix it with `@2x`, etc.